# is there any problem in this code that could prohibit my jumping ability in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am currently working on a project and have reached a phase where i downloaded the code that it showed in the tutorial but it seems to be outdated. it has now been fixed but for some reason it does not want to jump. is there anything wrong in my code that would cause my jumping ability not to work?

here is the code

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 

public CharacterController2D controller;

public float runSpeed = 40f;

float horizontalMove = 0f;
bool jump = false;
bool crouch = false;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        jump = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = true;
    } else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = false;
    }

}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Move our character
    controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
    jump = false;
}
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to make it reasonably answerable here.

Comment: If there's a compiler error, you have more information than it's "not valid". There's aine number, an error code and an error message. You need to give use some hints

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a `{` after the `public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour`.  Try this:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{
public CharacterController2D controller;

public float runSpeed = 40f;

float horizontalMove = 0f;
bool jump = false;
bool crouch = false;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        jump = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = true;
    } else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
    {
        crouch = false;
    }

}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Move our character
    controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
    jump = false;
}
}
```